# Troubleshoot Powershell script inside Chef recipe

Tags: powershell, chef-infra

I'm fairly new to Chef but I've gone through all the online tutorials and feel like I have a decent grasp on the basics. I'm trying to run a Powershell script from inside a recipe. The script itself runs fine from Powershell and updates the DNS IP settings as expected. When I run the recipe it also completes without error but the embedded script does't update the DNS settings so I'm assuming it's not executing properly and I'm not sure where to look for errors/logs.

The recipe is posted below and is executed via `chef-client.bat --local-mode --runlist 'recipe[prod_server::dns_settings]'`

```
   powershell_script 'Set DNS Servers' do
  code = <<-EOH
  $primary = "10.1.10.2"
     $secondary = "10.1.10.225"
     $DNSServers = "$primary","$secondary"
     $message=""
    function setDNS($DNSServers)
    {
       try
        {
          $NICs = Get-WMIObject Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration |where{$_.IPEnabled -eq "TRUE"}
          Foreach($NIC in $NICs)
       {
         $message += $NIC.SetDNSServerSearchOrder(@($DNSServers)) | Out-String   # set the DNS IPs and capture output to string
       }
          }
       catch
          {
      $message += "An error occcured while setting NIC object." + "`n`rError: $_";
          }
       #write-host $message #if necessary, display result messages
    }
    setDNS($DNSServers)
  EOH
     end
```

Comment: People familiar with both Chef and PowerShell are a bit of a niche. I would highly recommend asking on the Chef mailing list instead of on here, as I know several of them watch the list.

Comment: I would uncomment the write-host and run chef with -l debug, IIRC the powershell_script resource should print stdout and stderr in debug mode. (But this may depend on you version of chef too...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm 95% sure you're actually hitting an error while trying to run the script and not handling it correctly. I know because this exact error just happened to me, a silent failure and for me it was because of the double quotes.

Two Workarounds:

1. Remove all double quotes. Escaping MIGHT work but I've never had good luck with it.

`` powershell_script 'Set DNS Servers' do
  code = <<-EOH
  $primary = '10.1.10.2'
     $secondary = '10.1.10.225'
     $DNSServers = $primary,$secondary
     $message=''
    function setDNS($DNSServers)
    {
       try
        {
          $NICs = Get-WMIObject Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration |where{$_.IPEnabled -eq 'TRUE'}
          Foreach($NIC in $NICs)
       {
         $message += $NIC.SetDNSServerSearchOrder(@($DNSServers)) | Out-String   # set the DNS IPs and capture output to string
       }
          }
       catch
          {
      $message += 'An error occcured while setting NIC object.' + '`n`rError: $_';
          }
       #write-host $message #if necessary, display result messages
    }
    setDNS($DNSServers)
  EOH
     end ``

2. Put the script in a script file, write the file out as a resource, and then notify the execute resource to execute the powershell script:

```

```
script_path =
    win_friendly_path(File.join(Chef::Config[:file_cache_path],"os-permissions.ps1"))
  script_name = "os-permissions.ps1"

  execute script_name do  
    command "powershell \"#{script_path}\""  
    action :nothing  
  end  

  cookbook_file script_path do
    source "os-permissions.ps1"
    action :create
    notifies :run, "execute[#{script_name}]", :immediately
  end
```

With # 2, I have a script in my cookbook called os-permissions.ps1 in files\default\

I use # 2 when I can't remove all of the double quotes from my script. I also sometimes execute the scripts directly from the cookbook directly but that's not as straightforward and probably not best-practice (just me being lazy)

Comment: Thanks Nick. Removing double quotes did not work but I was able to get it to work using your 2nd method after adding "windows" and "chef_handler" cookbooks.

Comment: Nice!! I think you needed the windows cookbook becuase of the win_friendly_path() helper. I'm not sure why you needed the chef_handler cookbook, maybe it's because of the notification/subscription system.